# How to insert into database from netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Im trying to insert a new "elev" into my table, Im struggling with the query, the variables "id" and "sovsal" are integers. How is the query supposed to look like?

```
try {
    String nextID = db.getAutoIncrement("elev", "elev_id");
    angeElevID.setText(nextID);
    String id = angeElevID.getText();
    String sovsal = angeSovsal.getText();
    String efternamn = angeEfternamn.getText();
    String fornamn = angeFornamn.getText();

    db.insert("INSERT INTO ELEV values('" + id + "','" + fornamn + "','" + efternamn + "'," + sovsal + ")");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "En ny elev har lagts till");
} catch (InfException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "något blev fel");
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? PS: I don't think you need to put id under single quote(like this 'id'), because id is integer value

Comment: @Ankur Violation of foreign key constraint "INTEG_34" on table "ELEV" foreign key reference target does not exist
Problematic key value is ("SOVSAL" = 40)

Comment: @Leobd - that error pretty much tells you exactly what the problem is. You are trying to insert a record with a foreign key that doesn't exist... Try adding your DDL to the question so we can see how the tables are defined.

Comment: @Zephyr Can you make your Comment an Answer so this Question can be closed?

Answer (score 0):

So the query is like
`db.insert("INSERT INTO ELEV (tableElement1, tableElement2,tableElement3, tableElement4) values('"+id+"','"+fornamn+"','"+efternamn+"',"+sovsal+")");`

Where the tableElements are the names in the database